# Opening a specific file with the program specified in Python.

Tags: python, linux, maya

This is the python code I wrote to open a specific nuke file and a specific 3de file. The nuke works and opens the specific nuke file but the 3de doesn't. I get an error saying "3de: command not found". I'm trying to run this in from Maya to open through the terminal.

```
nFile="/sam/stuff/new.nk"
tFile="/sam/stuff/new.3de"



os.system("nuke %s &" %(nFile))    
os.system("3de %s &" %(tFile))
```

Comment: Use the full path to `3de`

Comment: Thanks dude I wrote in the full path and it gave me some more info in terminal to write in -open for 3de and worked. Final Code looks like this...

Comment: os.system("/desktop/3de4 -open %s &" %(tFile))

Comment: If you managed to self-answer your question, it is recommended to post and accept your own answer.

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up still new on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3de needed the full filepath and the 3de flag open in front of the project filepath. Easy fix thanks to /user/that other guy.

```
nFile="/sam/stuff/new.nk"
tFile="/sam/stuff/new.3de"



os.system("nuke %s &" %(nFile))    
os.system("/c/3de/3de -open %s &" %(tFile))
```